# Get index value from array with condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have a np array like that.

```
a = [ [0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
]
```

I want to get all rows index where in 3rd column if item value is ==1

```
a[:,2:2+1]==1
```

In that case my result would be
index = [0 3,3]
Is there any function that I can use for that?

Comment: There's no function. You need to write loops/list-comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0]])
index,value_first_at_index=np.where(a[:,2:3]==1)
print(index)
```

[image: e]